# abrir un pdf en android con una aplicacion ya instalada

Tags: android

tengo el siguiente codigo pero no reconoce el archivo

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/"+nombPdf;//Directory()+"/2555524_01012018_2390_RTF.pdf";//
    Toast.makeText(context, dir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File arch = new File(dir);
    if (arch.exists()) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(arch));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setType( "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try {
            Intent chooser = null;
            chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Abrir factura");
            startActivity(intent);
            //startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No existe una aplicación para abrir el PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

y los siguientes permisos en el manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: y los permisos??? esos no son

Comment: perdona podrías decirme donde esta el error. Gracias

Comment: Verificaste que el archivo .pdf en realidad exista en el directorio "Downloads"?, si es una aplicación que se instala, esta debe copiar el .pdf en ese directorio, dudo que se este realizando de esta forma. Además recuerda los permisos en OS 6.0 o posterior se requieren manualmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya encontré el problema era por la necesidad de usar file provider en las nuevas versiones de android
este sería el codigo que debería ir en el archivo manifest

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

este sería el código a poner en el xml que contiene las rutas de los  archivos

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    </paths>
```

y este el de la función que abre los archivos

```
    String s= String.valueOf(file);
    File arch = new File(s);
    if (arch.exists()) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", arch);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Utils.showSnackBar(root.getResources().getString(R.string.error_pdf), root);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por editarla. Recuerda que en 24h puedes marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

En  las nuevas versiones de android, androidx, éste seria el código que deberia ir en el archivo manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```